# Presiding impulse

Tags: word-usage, usage

I found the unfamiliar usage of **"preside"** in [this article](https://www.bbc.com/worklife/article/20220302-why-uncommon-baby-names-are-surging).

> In previous centuries, tradition-driven name conformity was the **presiding** impulse

According to [this dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/preside), **preside** means as follows

> to be in charge of a formal meeting, ceremony, or trial

However this meaning does not match the sentence.
How can I interpret this word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the same dictionary also gives as a definition of "preside":

> to be in charge of or to control a meeting or event:

and gives as an example of its use:

> *More than others, they reward incumbents who preside over strong national economies and punish those who do not.*

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preside) gives as the first sense of "preside:

> to exercise guidance, direction, or control

and as the second sense:

> to occupy the place of authority : act as president, chairman, or moderator

[Sictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/preside) gives:

> - 1 to occupy the place of authority or control, as in an assembly or meeting; act as president or chairperson.
> - 2 to exercise management or control (usually followed by over):
>   *The lawyer presided over the estate.*

I think it can be taken as a near-synonym of "rule", and that is the sense used in the quoted text:

> In previous centuries, tradition-driven name conformity was the **presiding** impulse

If I were writing that  text, I would have been inclined to use "prevailing", "controlling", "ruling", or "dominant" in place of "presiding", but the overall meaning would not have been significantly changed by any of those sources.

---

By the way, in future when quoting a text here, please give the source: at least the title and author from which the quote is taken, and if possible a link to the source. This allows readers to find additional context if it is wanted. It also gives proper credit.

Comment: "common impulse" is another related definition I believe and "overarching impulse" is an interesting alterative also.

Comment: @Eli Harold 
"common impulse"  is surely related, but would not carry the same sense of "in charge" that either "presiding" or any of my suggested alternatives do.  It would also, in this test, raise the question "common to whom?" "Overarching" would be another reasonable possibility

Comment: True, I believe "presiding" is a better choice, but "common" is a simple word that may help learners understand the term hence why I mentioned it. I also believe "common to whom?" would be the same thought as "presiding over what?" which I assume is answered with context.

Comment: @Eli Harold I would think that that "common impulse" means an impulse shared between 2 or more people , but this text does not indicate which two.  In this context "presiding" indicates in general control. "Dominant impulse" would have a similar meaning.

Comment: I haven't read the text the OP linked, but "presiding over whom?" must be apparent, no? Let me read it quickly, lol.

Comment: After reading, the context implies "across the globe" so I would imagine "common impulse" refers to that which is common "across the globe."